# Scalar-by-matrix Derivative of Quadratic Product

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, analysis, matrices, matrix-calculus

I'd like to know $\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{U})}{\partial \mathbf{U}}$, i.e., the 'by-matrix derivative' of the following scalar function $f(\mathbf{U})$ w.r.t. $\mathbf{U}$.

$$f(\mathbf{U}) = \vec{x}^T \mathbf{U} \mathbf{D} \mathbf{U}^T \vec{x}\;,$$

where $\vec{x} \in \mathbb{R}^n$ is a column vector, $\mathbf{U} \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$ is a unitary matrix ($\mathbf{U}^T\mathbf{U} = \mathbf{I}_n$), $\mathbf{D} \in \{0,1\}^{n \times n}$ is a diagonal matrix ($\mathbf{D} \neq \mathbf{I}_n$).

I found in [The Matrix Cookbook](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/pubdb/views/edoc_download.php/3274/pdf/imm3274.pdf), see eq. (82), the derivative $\frac{\partial g(\mathbf{U})}{\partial \mathbf{U}}$
 of

$$g(\mathbf{U}) = \vec{x}^T \mathbf{U}^T \mathbf{D} \mathbf{U} \vec{x}\;.$$

Please note the difference in the transposition of $\mathbf{U}$ for $f(\mathbf{U})$ and $g(\mathbf{U})$.

From the earlier question "[Derivative of inverse quadratic function of a matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/47648/derivative-of-inverse-quadratic-function-of-a-matrix)" I learned that $\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{U})}{\partial u_{ij}} = \vec{x}^T (\mathbf{U} \mathbf{D} \mathbf{J}^{ij} + \mathbf{J}^{ji} \mathbf{D} \mathbf{U}^T) \vec{x}$. Unfortunately, I can't figure out how to combine it to a 'closed matrix notation'. I end up with $\frac{\partial f(\mathbf{U})}{\partial u_{ij}} = \mathbf{D}\mathbf{U}^T\vec{x}\vec{x}^T \vert_{ij} + \vec{x}\vec{x}^T\mathbf{U}\mathbf{D}\vert_{ji}$.

Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A straightforward way is to compute
$f(U+H) = x^T (U+H) D (U+H)^T x = f(U)+x^T HDU^Tx + x^TUDH^T x + f(H)$,
and note that $|f(H)| \le K \|H\|^2$ for some $K$.

It follows that the derivative is given by
$Df(U)(H) = x^T HDU^Tx + x^TUDH^T x$. Since $f$ is real valued and $D^T=D$, we can write
$Df(U)(H) = 2x^TUDH^T x$.

We have ${ \partial f(U) \over \partial U_{ij} } = Df(U)(E_{ij}) = 2x^TUD E_{ji} x = 2x^TUD e_j e_i^T x$.

**Comments**:

This is the definition (or one of a few equivalents) of differentiability:

A function $f:V \to W$ where $V,W$ are Banach spaces is said to be (Fréchet) differentiable at $x$ **iff** there exists a continuous linear operator $A:V \to W$ such that for all $\epsilon>0$, there exists some $\delta >0$ such that if $\|h\| <\delta$, then
$\|f(x+h)-f(x) - A(h) \| \le \epsilon \|h\|$. The operator $A$ is called the derivative of $f$ at $x$.

**A few points**:

(1) In our case, $V=\mathbb{R}^{n \times n}$, $W = \mathbb{R}$.

(2) The derivative operator is often denoted  $Df(x)$. Note that $Df(x):V \to W$. So, given $h \in V$, we write $Df(x)(h) \in W$ to denote the operator applied to $h$ (perhaps think of $h$ as a perturbation).

(3) The idea of differentiability is to quantify the difference $f(x+h)-f(x)$ in some way. Some folks write $f(x+h) =f(x)+A(h) + o(h)$.

(4) The linear operator $A$ cannot always be expressed as a matrix multiplication. For example, take the trace $\operatorname{tr}: \mathbb{R}^{n \times n} \to \mathbb{R}$. This is a differentiable function, but you cannot
write down a single matrix multiplication that represents the derivative (in fact, we have $D \operatorname{tr}(x)(h) = \operatorname{tr}(h)$). This is a confusing point for many folks as we typically (in the $\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^m$ case) write the derivative as a matrix multiplication. The derivative of the function $f$ above **cannot** be written as a simple matrix multiplication.

**To answer the questions in your comment below**:

To compute the derivative of $f$, we compute $f(U+H)-f(U)$ and look for linear and higher order terms. We have
$f(U+H)-f(U) = x^T HDU^Tx + x^TUDH^T x + f(H)$, the term $H \mapsto x^T HDU^Tx + x^TUDH^T x$ is linear (and continuous) in $H$, and the term $f(H)$ can be bounded by $K\|H\|^2$. Hence from the definition, we see that $f$ is differentiable at $U$, and the derivative applied to the direction $H$ is given by $Df(U)(H) = x^T HDU^Tx + x^TUDH^T x$. The derivative is a function
$Df(U): \mathbb{R}^{n\times n} \to \mathbb{R}$, but cannot be written as a simply matrix multiplication of some matrix and $H$.

The expression $Df(U)(H) = x^T HDU^Tx + x^TUDH^T x$ completely defines the derivative of $f$.

**Now for a slight backtrack**: While what I wrote above is correct, there is a sense in which you can write down a single object that represents the derivative.

From above, we can write (using properties of the trace operator)
$Df(U)(H) = 2x^T HDU^Tx = \operatorname{tr} (2x^T HDU^Tx) = \operatorname{tr}( 2 DU^Txx^T H )  = \operatorname{tr}( (2 xx^T U D )^T H )$.

If one uses the Frobenius norm and the corresponding inner product, we see that we can write $Df(U)(H) = \langle 2 xx^T U D, H \rangle $, so we can write the gradient $\nabla f(U) = 2 xx^T U D$.

However, you must realise that this is not just a simple matrix multiplication, and that the trace is intimately involved.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately, I don't understand everything. First, why do we have to consider $f(\mathbf{U} + \mathbf{H})$? I don't get the meaning of $\mathbf{H}$. Second, why does "It follows that the derivative is given by $\mathbf{D}f(\mathbf{U})\mathbf{H}$". For me it looks like you take $f(\mathbf{U} + \mathbf{H}) - f(\mathbf{U}) - f(\mathbf{H})$. Finally, can you write the derivative w.r.t. to the whole matrix $\mathbf{U}$, rather than for each entry $U_{ij}$?

Comment: @tmp: I started writing a quick reply and it expanded too much so I added info. to the answer. Hopefully it addresses your questions.

Comment: Your extended reply fully addresses and answers my question! Thank you very much. I was hoping that, since (according to eq. (82) in 'The Matrix Cookbook') $\frac{\partial g(\mathbf{U})}{\partial \mathbf{U}} = 2\mathbf{D}\mathbf{U}\vec{x}\vec{x}^T$ a similar result can be obtained for $f(\mathbf{U})$ and you affirmed that. I am grateful for pointing out the reason for that result, your detailed explanation and the insight into the Fréchet differential operator as well as the 'trick' with the trace operator and the Frobenius inner product.

Answer (score 1):

Let $W = x^TUD$ and rewrite the function using the Frobenius product as
$$ \eqalign {
 f &= \|W\|_F^2 \cr
   &= W:W \cr
} $$
For which the differential is
$$ \eqalign {
 df &= 2\,W:dW \cr
    &= 2\,(x^TUD):d\,(x^TUD) \cr
    &= 2\,(x^TUD):(x^TdU\,D) \cr
    &= 2\,(xx^TUDD^T):dU \cr
    &= 2\,(xx^TUD):dU \cr
    &= \bigg(\frac {\partial f} {\partial U}\bigg):dU \cr
} $$
From the last 2 lines, the derivative must be
$$ \eqalign {
 \frac {\partial f} {\partial U} &= 2\,xx^TUD \cr
} $$
NB: In several of the steps above, I made use of the fact that $D^T=D=D^2$