# Gradient of $\log\det$ of sum of two matrices

Tags: matrices, derivatives, determinant, matrix-calculus, scalar-fields

Let $A$ and $X$ be two symmetric (semi)positive definite matrices, I was wondering how to calculate the gradient with respect to $X$ of

$$ X \mapsto \log\det(A+X),$$

where $\det$ is the determinant of a matrix.

In the second order case, let $X\in \mathbb{R}^{m\times n}$ ($m>n$) be a rectangle matrix, $A$ and $B$ are $m\times m$ and $n\times n$  symmetric (semi)positive definite matrices. Then, what is the gradient of

$$ X \mapsto \log \det \left( X B X^\top + A \right) $$

with respect to $X$?

Comment: [Somewhat related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1953518/339790)

Comment: [Related](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1493137/339790)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Define a new (symmetric) matrix 
$$\eqalign{
 Y &= (X+A) \implies dY = dX \cr
}$$ 
Write the function in terms of this new variable. Then find its differential and gradient.
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \log\big(\det(Y)\big) \cr
d\phi &= d\log(\det(Y)) = d\,{\rm tr}(\log(Y)) = Y^{-1}:dY \cr
 &= (X+A)^{-1}:dX \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X} &= (X+A)^{-1} \cr
}$$
For the second problem let
$$\eqalign{
 Y &= (XBX^T+A) \cr
dY &= (dX\,BX^T + XB\,dX^T) = 2\,{\rm sym}(dX\,BX^T) \cr
}$$ 
Then
$$\eqalign{
\phi &= \log\big(\det(Y)\big) \cr
d\phi &= Y^{-1}:dY \cr
 &= Y^{-1}:2\,{\rm sym}(dX\,BX^T) \cr
 &= 2Y^{-1}:dX\,BX^T \cr
 &= 2Y^{-1}XB:dX \cr
 &= 2(XBX^T+A)^{-1}XB:dX \cr
\frac{\partial\phi}{\partial X} &= 2(XBX^T+A)^{-1}XB \cr
\cr
}$$
In some of the steps above, a colon was used to represent the trace/Frobenius product
$$A:B = {\rm tr}(A^TB)$$
and **sym** to represent the function 
$${\rm sym}(A) = \frac{1}{2}(A+A^T)$$

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! Is there any (introductory-level) textbook I can read to learn matrix calculus?

Comment: Hello @frank, I really find your solutions similar to the other like greg's in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1217908/matrix-derivatives-of-determinant-and-inverse-related-to-mathbfx-mathbfx quite fascinating. Is there a textbook that teaches you this general procedure of yours?